# How to deal with multiple intents in notification in Android?

Tags: android

So, I've an issue as such:

I've written a service that has the notification receiver and which also calls the function notify(). My problem is this, similar to twitter, on a successful update I want to notify the user that the update was posted. And, if the update wasn't then I want to notify the user that the update has failed. When the update is posted, and user clicks on the notification, he or she will be taken to one activity. If the update isn't posted, and the user clicks on the notification, then the user will be taken to another activity that might have the drafts. Notification text/image would also change depending upon if the post was done or not. As of now, I'm able to post just one single text and not able to call notify() function from anywhere else thus becoming a huge trouble in building this notification system. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Where do you decide if the update was successful or failed? I'm probably missing something as I'm not sure what the problem is with simply adding a different notification in case of success/failure.

Comment: But, won't the notification stack up?

Comment: From what I understand: You're doing something, waiting for a result and then decide on the notification,right? If so, simply add a notification according to the result... But I'm probably missing something, please clarify

Comment: Ok. So, what I want to do is three basic things: 1: Show the user that he has posted an update with the text "Posting update" 2: If update fails, "Update failed" and when he clicks on that, he is taken to an activity. 3: If update is success, "update success" and when he clicks on that he is taken to another activity. Some pseudo code would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create notification ("Updating..."), keep it's tag

on success -> cancel the "updating" notification (using it's tag) and create a new notification ("success")

on failure -> cancel the "updating" notification (using it's tag) and create a new notification ("failure")

Each of these notifications should have different PendingIntents (with differnet ids) which perform a different action (e.g. open a different activity) when clicked.